# Webmin turn off anti iframe protection

Tags: webmin

How can I disable anti iframe protection / cross-orign access? My webmin is located at `https://webmin.SOMEDOMAIN.com/` and page with iframe is in `http://admin.SOMEDOMAIN.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to "Referrer checking enabled"/ Trusted website options, it is configured at this address: https://webmin.SOMEDOMAIN.com//webmin/edit_referers.cgi